# How to catch event onclick without ng-click Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing an Angular App but I want to catch onclick event without ng-click, I want to use something like that

`$scope.onClick(...)`

Comment: Why? what purpose would that serve?

Comment: @KevinB I want to separate all logic and use event handlers for it.

Comment: but... that's what ng-click does... binds event handlers... you can still have the handler defined in the controller.

Comment: You could use a directive, but then... you'd have ot put the directive on the html, just like ng-click, so it's no better.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid `ng-click`, you're probably looking for a different framework. Backbone.js does what you're describing pretty much.

Comment: lol very strange indeed :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJs use **directive** to operate dom. you can add a directive like this.

**AngularJs**

```
YourApp.directive('testClick', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.onclick = function() {
                //do some thing.
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**html**

```
<button test-click>Test Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're trying to click. If we're talking about normal DOM,you could use the regular, non-angular way of doing this.

I.e.

Assuming for an element like

```
<div id="elementID" onclick = "clicked">Element</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function clicked(){
     console.log("I was triggered!");
}
var element = document.getElementById('elementID');
element.onclick = function(){
     console.log("I was also triggererd!"); 
}
```

Or even use JQuery if you want:

```
$('#elementID').bind('click', function () {
    console.log("I would also be triggered!");
});
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use with Angular.js

Comment: So why exactly do you want to use onclick() without ng-click()?

Comment: Because I have all my logic on Angular Controller and services, but I want to declare on my Controller something like $scope.Element.OnClick(...)

Comment: But what difference does it make to have $scope.clickfunc = function(){...} with 'ng-click = "clickfunc()"' instead of what you want? Theres almost no reason to use onclick as angular provides you with the ng-click functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The only way it worked for me was:

**JS:**

```
    .directive('testClick', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                element.on('click', function() {
                    console.log('Clicked');
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

**HTML:**

```
<button test-click> Here </button>
```